# How to add such content table in my research paper?

Tags: table-of-contents, latex3

How to add such content table in my research paper ?

I am using `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}`

[image]

I want to cite or call the page numbers also in the table-content.

Please add few examples.

**Edit:**

According to suggested example by @Simon, I got

[image]

**But why it is red color rather than black?**

Comment: Insert `\tableofcontents` to your document body. For links between `\tableofcontents` and sections, subsections, etc you should load `hyperref package` too. BTW, your question is probably downvoted because you not provide any information about your document (used document class, etc) nor what you try so far etc )(I didn't downvote, but I suggest to close  your question as *Needs details or clarity*).

Comment: @Zarko, thank you. But I said I am using `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}`

Comment: You may consider to read  https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.  There are described basic how to use LaTeX.

Comment: @Zarko, thank  you very much

Comment: Sorry, this is not sufficient. At least you should show small document as `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart} \begin{document}\tableofcontents \section{name 1}\section{name 2}\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template might guide you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%dummy text

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}   

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction and notation}
\kant[1]    
\section{Rings of power series}
\kant[2-4]
\section{Overconvergent substitution maps}
\kant[3-6]
\section{Eingenvalues}
\kant[4]
\section{Substitutions of finite heights}
\kant[5]
\section{The operator}
\kant[6]
\section{The space}
\kant[7]
\section{Convergence close to the origin}
\kant[8-9]
\section*{References}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter H]

**UPDATE** cite page number, abstract and blue hyperlinks

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%dummy text  

\usepackage{hyperref}   
\hypersetup{% 
    colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    linktocpage=true, % in the table of contents, make page numbers rather than associated text into hyperlinks
} %

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}   

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}        
        We will start with the concepts of \emph{Rings} in page~\pageref{sec:s1} to cover the \emph{substitution maps} (page~\pageref{sec:s2}).
    Next we will calcule the \emph{Eingenvalues} (page~\pageref{sec:s3}).
    
    \emph{The Operator} and \emph{the space} will be addressed in pages~\pageref{sec:s5} and \pageref{sec:s6} respectively.
\end{abstract}

\section*{Introduction and notation} \label{sec:s0}
\kant[1-5]  
\section{Rings of power series}\label{sec:s1}
\kant[2-4]
\section{Overconvergent substitution maps}\label{sec:s2}
\kant[3-7]
\section{Eingenvalues}\label{sec:s3}
\kant[4-9]
\section{Substitutions of finite heights}\label{sec:s4}
\kant[5-8]
\section{The operator}\label{sec:s5}
\kant[6-9]
\section{The space}\label{sec:s6}
\kant[7-9]
\section{Convergence close to the origin}\label{sec:s7}
\kant[8-9]
\section*{References}\label{sec:sR}
\end{document}
```

[image: fff6]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful

Comment: I want to add abstract before the table-content.How to do this ?

Comment: My content table is becoming red color. Why ?  I am using `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}`

Comment: Please see the updated answer for the abstract and citing page numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes but I am getting red color content table.See my edited question and the previous above comment

Comment: It is ok. I got it.Thanks

Comment: I added hyperlinks. It is better to have them with some color, not black, to make possible to  the reader to see  them.

Comment: Sorry, but final question. Can I enclose the page numbers showing in the content table within brace `[ ]`  ?

Comment: TeX.SE (like all StackExchange sites) doesn't work well with multiple follow up questions.  You might have better luck providing a minimal example in a new question.

Comment: @Teepeemm I was going to say the same. Thank you.